# Does XAMPP use MariaDB or MySQL?

Tags: xampp

I'm using XAMPP v3.2.2 to connect MySQL database via JDBC. For this I downloaded MySQL JDBC driver and connecting successfully. One thing that I confused in does the XAMPP use MariaDB or MYSQL? In homepage of XAMPP it says "XAMPP Apache + MariaDB + PHP + Perl" but  in the application side it shows MYSQL. And there's any setup files related to MariaDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XAMPP switched from MySQL to MariaDB. Since MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for MySQL, you will see some folders with mysql as name but MariaDB behind it.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace MariaDB and MySQL as you see fit. MariaDB is built to be 100% compatible with MySQL and is a drop in replacement.

It is up to personal preference ... try it ... you will be amazed at how it works.

There are obviously some difference in features but at the core the connectivity to the different systems uses the same connection string.

Comment: So it means that their JDBC drivers are same?

Comment: @niso: I don't think there are specific drivers for MariaDB ... I have always use the MySQL ones.

Answer (score 1):

Xampp currently uses Mariadb which is a fork and drop in replacement for mysql. Mysql connector J (jdbc driver for mysql) works just fine on Mariadb. Mariadb too has its own jdbc connector(which does not work with Mysql). Mariadb prompt also includes the name Mariadb at the prompt just like Mysql includes the name mysql at the prompt